# How to validate URLs for ATOM and RSS feeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a field in my form which is supposed to accept ATOM and RSS feeds as input, how do I write validation code in my model which validate that only feeds have been provided as input.

Comment: Do you want the feed-url (and check if the input is actually a url), or do you want the whole text of the feed?

Comment: I want to know that it is a proper RSS or ATOM feed URL, I don't need the text rendered by it at this juncture.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://github.com/bantic/feeddetector/blob/master/feed_detector.rb#L35) from feed detector.
yes, it detects feed, but you can use the regex to check if the model's url match it

from the code:

```
  matches |= html.scan(/<link.*href=['"]*([^\s'"]+)['"]*.*application\/atom\+xml.*>/)
  matches |= html.scan(/<link.*application\/atom\+xml.*href=['"]*([^\s'"]+)['"]*.*>/)
  #  matches |=  atom_feed

  matches |= html.scan(/<link.*href=['"]*([^\s'"]+)['"]*.*application\/rss\+xml.*>/)
  matches |= html.scan(/<link.*application\/rss\+xml.*href=['"]*([^\s'"]+)['"]*.*>/)
  #  matches |= rss_feed
```

Comment: Be careful, it's not really a good idea to insert blocking code in model validations directly.

Comment: @Badfoo Is there a better way to achieve without the above blocking code

Comment: I didn't mean to use the scan line for validations. I meant so you can use the regex with validates_format_of or something similiar

Answer (score 0):

Basically any valid URL can be a valid RSS/Atom URL. The only way to find out is to hit that URL and check if the content recieved is parseable as RSS/Atom.